# Absolutely convergence of the Fourier coefficients for cosine terms

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a **merely continuous** function on $[0,\pi]$. Let $c_n$ be the cosine Fourier coefficients of $f$. Then does $\sum |c_n|$ converge or not?

I can prove the situation when $f$ is derivable.
$$\left. \begin{array}{l}{ c _ n = \int _ { 0 } ^ { \pi } f ( x ) \cos n x d x }\\{ = - \frac { 1 } { n } \cdot \int _ { 0 } ^ { \pi } f ^ { \prime } ( x ) \sin n x d x }\\{ = - \frac { A _ n } { n } }\end{array} \right.$$
Then $\sum | c _ { n } | = \sum | \frac { A _ { n } } { n } | \leq \frac { 1 } { 2 } ( \sum\frac { 1 } { n ^ { 2 } } + \sum A _ { n } ^ { 2 } )<+\infty$.

$\sum_{n>1}\frac{\sin nx}{n\ln n}$is a
counterexample for the sine term and I want to know how about the cosine term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fejer's example of a continuous function with a divergent FS (see 10.3.1, p. 154 of 'Fourier Series' by Edwards) is a cosine series. It is divergent at $0$. But if $f$ is any function whose Fourier coefficients $(c_n)$ satisfy $\sum |c_n| <\infty$ then the function is continuous and the Fourier series converges to $f$ at every point.